# Can I do a for loop over variables in the bash shell?

Tags: linux, shell, variables

I'm learning the shell, and I want to be able to loop over some variables. I can't seem to find anywhere where anyone has done this so I'm not sure it's even possible.

Basically I just want to save myself trouble by using the same sed command on each of these variables. However the code obviously doesn't work. My question is, is it possible to loop over variables and if not how should I be doing this?

```
title="$(echo string1)"
artist="$(echo string2)"
album="$(echo string3)"

for arg in title artist album do
    $arg="$(echo "$arg" | sed -e 's/&/\&amp;/g' -e 's/</\&lt;/g' -e 's/>/\&gt;/g')"
done
```

here is the error:

```
line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `$arg="$(echo "$arg" | sed -e 's/&/\&amp;/g' -e 's/</\&lt;/g' -e 's/>/\&gt;/g')"'
```

Comment: What's the error when you run the code? (Assuming you're referring to something that the syntax highlighting didn't already point out to you...)

Comment: Another common way to do this type of problem is to do something like:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the loop, it's with the assignment. The variable name needs to be literal in an assignment, i.e. you can write `title=some_value` but not `$arg=some_value`.

A portable way to assign to a variably-named variable is to use `eval`. You also need to obtain the value of `$arg` (not just the value of `arg`, which is `$arg`), which again requires using `eval`.

```
new_value="$(eval printf %s \"\$$arg\" | …)"
eval $arg=\$new_value
```

Another way to assign to a variably-named variable that's specific to bash/ksh/zsh but won't work in plain sh is to use the `typeset` built-in. In bash, if you do this in a function, this makes the assignment local to the function. To obtain the value of the variably-named variable, you can use `${!arg}`; this is specific to bash.

```
typeset $arg="$(printf %s "${!arg}" | …)"
```

Other problems with your snippet:

- `title="$(echo string1)"` is a complicated way to write `title="string1"`, which furthermore may mangle `string1` if it contains backslashes or begins with `-`.
- You need a command terminator (`;` or newline) before the `do` keyword.

If you're relying on bash/ksh/zsh, you can make the replacements inside the shell with the `${VARIABLE//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` construct.

```
title="string1"
artist="string2"
album="string3"
for arg in title artist album; do
  eval value=\$$arg
  value=${value//&/&amp;}
  value=${value//</&lt;}
  value=${value//>/&gt;}
  eval $arg=\$value
done
```

Comment: this is fantastic. I tried it out and actually it didn't quite work (I'm trying the portable route). Here's what I came up with:

    `new_value="$(eval printf %s \"\$$arg\" | sed -e 's/&/\\&amp;/g' -e 's/</\\&lt;/g' -e 's/>/\\&gt;/g')"
    eval arg=\$new_value`

I had to add a second $ to the printf statement or else new_value would equal "title" "album" or "artist". I also removed the $ from the second eval statement or else that would equal "title" etc..

oh and for curiosity's sake why does there have to be a \$ before new_value on the second line as opposed to just $?

Comment: @Dennis: Sorry, the missing `$` in the `printf` call was a typo. I don't see anything wrong with any of the others, which one did you mean? In `eval $arg=\$new_value`, the string to evaluate is something like `title=$new_value`, which assigns the value of `new_value` to the variable `title`. If you wrote `eval $arg=$new_value`, the string to evaluate would be e.g. `title=Apostrophe (')`: the new value would be used as shell code, not as a literal string.