# Find empty variables in bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sh

I have multiple variables in an array, I want to loop through each of those variables and find if they are empty.

Code:

```
declare -a CONFIG_PARAM=( $Var_MODE $Var_Path $Var_Stage $Var_line $Var_CVG $Var_Operator )
for PARAMS in "${CONFIG_PARAM[@]}"; do 
   if [ ! $PARAMS ]; then 
      echo -e "$PARAMS is empty"
   fi
done;
```

But it doesnt seem to catch the empty variables. Can someone point out what is wrong or provide any suggestion/solution? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Quotes. `"$Var_MODE" "$Var_PATH"` etc. And `[ ! "$PARAMS" ]`

Comment: But that's only if you needed the values. If you need the names, then you need to use an indirect expansion.

Comment: Thanks I just tried the and got the values but I needed the variable names to be printed!

Comment: Hmm. Arguably this is a duplicate of [can I do a for loop over variables in the bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394682/can-i-do-a-for-loop-over-variables-in-the-bash-shell)

Answer (score 3):

```
declare -a config_params=( Var_MODE Var_Path Var_Stage Var_line Var_CVG Var_Operator )
for param in "${config_params[@]}"; do 
   if ! [ -n "${!param}" ]; then 
      echo "$param is empty"
   fi
done
```

Note:

- Always quote expansions. If you don't do this, an empty string doesn't evaluate to anything at all -- so `[ ! $empty ]` becomes `[ ! ]` if `empty` is empty. And `[ ! ]` is equivalent to `[ -n ! ]`, so it evaluates as true. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words.
- Using `${!var}` expands the variable whose name is contained in `var`. See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables).
- Avoid all-caps variable names. See relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, reserving names with lower-case characters for application use, while indicating that the shell and/or POSIX utilities shall use upper-case variables for their own purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. But I have tried the code above, it still prints the values of variables instead of the varible names.

Comment: @GopinathS, ...uh... no, it doesn't. See this code actually running at https://ideone.com/4iUpnd

Comment: My bad, I didn't remove '$' for variables in the array, sorry about that. Now I understood the indirect-reference concept from your note. Thanks a lot, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where (IMO) the loop makes your code less readable. There is something to be said for a nice vertical list of calls, one line per variable.

```
check_empty () {
    [ -z "${!1}" ] && printf '%s is empty\n' "$1"
}
```

and make a separate call for each variable.

```
check_empty Var_MODE
check_empty Var_Path
check_empty Var_Stage
check_empty Var_line
check_empty Var_CVG
check_empty Var_Operator
```

Actually, you don't even need a separate function. The parameter expansion operator `:?` will display an error message, with the name of the variable, if it is empty.

```
: ${Var_MODE?empty} || :
: ${Var_Path?empty} || :
: ${Var_Stage?empty} || :
: ${Var_line?empty} || :
: ${Var_CVG?empty} || :
: ${Var_Operator?empty} || :
```

The trailing `|| :` prevents the script from exiting when the variable is empty.